# MultiThreading in Jfoenix ChipView suggestions

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

I am implementing suggestions with ChipView from the [Jfoenix library](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix) and it works just fine when using a small list of data but with a big amount it blocks the UI. I want to implement Multithreading to resolve this problem but coudn't figure out how . Any Help ?

Comment: See [JavaFX concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm)

Comment: yes I already did, i know how to use it but not with chipView my need is very specific to chipView